# PHP - Check if element exists in this Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm retrieving a database record which is stored in a variable $record. If I do a:

```
echo '<p><pre>'.print_r($record).'</pre></p>';
```

I get the following:

```
    FileMaker_Record Object
(
    [_impl] => FileMaker_Record_Implementation Object
        (
            [_fields] => Array
                (
                    [Title] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Alaska 24/7
                        )

                    [Status] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Popular
                        )

                    [Author] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Rick Smolan and David Elliot Cohen
                        )

                    [Publisher] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => DK Publishing
                        )

                    [Cover Photo Credit] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Evan R. Steinhauser, Anchorage Daily News
                        )

                    [Description] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => The remarkable photographs showcased in Alaska 24/7 are the result of an epic project, America 24/7, which harnessed the talents of more than 25,000 photographers. 
                        )

                    [Quantity in Stock] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 50
                        )

                    [Number of Pages] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 192
                        )

                    [Cover Image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /fmi/xml/cnt/AK-cover.jpg?-db=FMPHP_Sample&-lay=Form%20View&-recid=1&-field=Cover%20Image(1)
                        )

                )

            [V5e7ec2d5] => Array
                (
                )

            [_recordId] => 1
            [_modificationId] => 2
            [_layout] => FileMaker_Layout Object
                (
                    [_impl] => FileMaker_Layout_Implementation Object
                        (
                            [_fm] => FileMaker_Implementation Object
                                (
                                    [V73ee434e] => Array
                                        (
                                            [charset] => UTF-8
                                            [locale] => en
                                            [logLevel] => 3
                                            [hostspec] => 127.0.01
                                            [recordClass] => FileMaker_Record
                                            [prevalidate] => 
                                            [database] => FMPHP_Sample
                                            [username] => admin
                                            [password] => testing123
                                        )

                                    [Vea4b3413] => 
                                    [V9a3dcbce] => 
                                )

                            [_name] => Form View
                            [_fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [Title] => FileMaker_Field Object
                                        (
                                            [_impl] => FileMaker_Field_Implementation Object
                                                (
                                                    [_layout] => FileMaker_Layout Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                    [_name] => Title
                                                    [_autoEntered] => 
                                                    [_global] => 
                                                    [_maxRepeat] => 1
                                                    [_validationMask] => 0
                                                    [_validationRules] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [_result] => text
                                                    [_type] => normal
                                                    [_valueList] => 
                                                    [_styleType] => 
                                                    [_maxCharacters] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Status] => FileMaker_Field Object
                                        (
                                            [_impl] => FileMaker_Field_Implementation Object
                                                (
                                                    [_layout] => FileMaker_Layout Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                    [_name] => Status
                                                    [_autoEntered] => 
                                                    [_global] => 
                                                    [_maxRepeat] => 1
                                                    [_validationMask] => 0
                                                    [_validationRules] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [_result] => text
                                                    [_type] => normal
                                                    [_valueList] => 
                                                    [_styleType] => 
                                                    [_maxCharacters] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Author] => FileMaker_Field Object
                                        (
                                            [_impl] => FileMaker_Field_Implementation Object
                                                (
                                                    [_layout] => FileMaker_Layout Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                    [_name] => Author
                                                    [_autoEntered] => 
                                                    [_global] => 
                                                    [_maxRepeat] => 1
                                                    [_validationMask] => 0
                                                    [_validationRules] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [_result] => text
                                                    [_type] => normal
                                                    [_valueList] => 
                                                    [_styleType] => 
                                                    [_maxCharacters] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Publisher] => FileMaker_Field Object
                                        (
                                            [_impl] => FileMaker_Field_Implementation Object
                                                (
                                                    [_layout] => FileMaker_Layout Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                    [_name] => Publisher
                                                    [_autoEntered] => 
                                                    [_global] => 
                                                    [_maxRepeat] => 1
                                                    [_validationMask] => 0
                                                    [_validationRules] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [_result] => text
                                                    [_type] => normal
                                                    [_valueList] => 
                                                    [_styleType] => 
                                                    [_maxCharacters] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Cover Photo Credit] => FileMaker_Field Object
                                        (
                                            [_impl] => FileMaker_Field_Implementation Object
                                                (
                                                    [_layout] => FileMaker_Layout Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                    [_name] => Cover Photo Credit
                                                    [_autoEntered] => 
                                                    [_global] => 
                                                    [_maxRepeat] => 1
                                                    [_validationMask] => 0
                                                    [_validationRules] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [_result] => text
                                                    [_type] => normal
                                                    [_valueList] => 
                                                    [_styleType] => 
                                                    [_maxCharacters] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Description] => FileMaker_Field Object
                                        (
                                            [_impl] => FileMaker_Field_Implementation Object
                                                (
                                                    [_layout] => FileMaker_Layout Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                    [_name] => Description
                                                    [_autoEntered] => 
                                                    [_global] => 
                                                    [_maxRepeat] => 1
                                                    [_validationMask] => 0
                                                    [_validationRules] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [_result] => text
                                                    [_type] => normal
                                                    [_valueList] => 
                                                    [_styleType] => 
                                                    [_maxCharacters] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Quantity in Stock] => FileMaker_Field Object
                                        (
                                            [_impl] => FileMaker_Field_Implementation Object
                                                (
                                                    [_layout] => FileMaker_Layout Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                    [_name] => Quantity in Stock
                                                    [_autoEntered] => 
                                                    [_global] => 
                                                    [_maxRepeat] => 1
                                                    [_validationMask] => 0
                                                    [_validationRules] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [_result] => number
                                                    [_type] => normal
                                                    [_valueList] => 
                                                    [_styleType] => 
                                                    [_maxCharacters] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Number of Pages] => FileMaker_Field Object
                                        (
                                            [_impl] => FileMaker_Field_Implementation Object
                                                (
                                                    [_layout] => FileMaker_Layout Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                    [_name] => Number of Pages
                                                    [_autoEntered] => 
                                                    [_global] => 
                                                    [_maxRepeat] => 1
                                                    [_validationMask] => 0
                                                    [_validationRules] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [_result] => number
                                                    [_type] => normal
                                                    [_valueList] => 
                                                    [_styleType] => 
                                                    [_maxCharacters] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Cover Image] => FileMaker_Field Object
                                        (
                                            [_impl] => FileMaker_Field_Implementation Object
                                                (
                                                    [_layout] => FileMaker_Layout Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                    [_name] => Cover Image
                                                    [_autoEntered] => 
                                                    [_global] => 
                                                    [_maxRepeat] => 1
                                                    [_validationMask] => 0
                                                    [_validationRules] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [_result] => container
                                                    [_type] => normal
                                                    [_valueList] => 
                                                    [_styleType] => 
                                                    [_maxCharacters] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [_relatedSets] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [_valueLists] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [Vab234ad8] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [_database] => FMPHP_Sample
                            [_extended] => 
                        )

                )

            [_fm] => FileMaker_Implementation Object
                (
                    [V73ee434e] => Array
                        (
                            [charset] => UTF-8
                            [locale] => en
                            [logLevel] => 3
                            [hostspec] => 127.0.0.1
                            [recordClass] => FileMaker_Record
                            [prevalidate] => 
                            [database] => FMPHP_Sample
                            [username] => admin
                            [password] => testing123
                        )

                    [Vea4b3413] => 
                    [V9a3dcbce] => 
                )

            [_relatedSets] => Array
                (
                )

            [_parent] => 
        )

)
```

I need to do some checking to see if the field I'm after exists in the list of fields returned with the $record object. For example I would like to see if the field 'Status' is contained within the  [_fields] => Array list of fields (would be true in this example).

I'm assuming I can use something like this:

```
if (in_array('Status', _fields)) {
```

but not sure of the exact syntax here and haven't been able to get this to work so far.

Comment: looked at the isset function in php?

Comment: Use `array_key_exists()` ?

Comment: Be more specific. What field you want to check? in_array is correct, but in your case you are asking to check an array against another array - _fields is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have an embedded object called FileMaker_Record_Implementation Object. Might be worth seeing if you have access to the source code of this Class as it may provide getters/setters for the attributes within.

Or you could try directly accessing the property like this:

```
if(!isset($record->_impl->_fields['Status'])){
    // Status doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isset()` or `array_key_exists()` functions for checking,
but they both are not the same.

`array_key_exists()` only checks if key exists even if the value is NULL.

`isset()` always return false if key exist and value is NULL.